# Ruby On Rails: Make controller smaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have this controller, it gets the data from the uploaded file and save it to the right models. I made it work, but it is gigantic. I would like some directions of how to make it smaller. Should I create a class to extract the data and save to the db?

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
require 'csv'
def save_info_to_db
    file = params[:file]
    purchases_made = []
    CSV.open(file.path, "r", { col_sep: "\t", headers: true }).each do |row|
        data = Hash.new
        data = {
            purchaser: { name: row[0] },
            item: { description: row[1], price: row[2], quantity: row[3] },
            merchant: { name: row[4], address: row[5] }
        }
        merchant = Merchant.create_with(address: data[:merchant_address]).find_or_create_by(name: data[:merchant][:name])
        item = merchant.items.create_with(price: data[:item][:price]).find_or_create_by(description: data[:item][:description])
        purchaser = Purchaser.create(name: data[:purchaser][:name])
        purchase = purchaser.purchases.create
        purchase_items = PurchaseItem.create(item_id: item.id, quantity: data[:item][:quantity])
        purchase.add_purchase_items(purchase_items)
        purchases_made << purchase.total_price
    end
    session[:total_gross_income] = Purchase.total_gross_income(purchases_made)
    redirect_to display_incomes_path
end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you should use services. Also, you should not use non-standard methods such as `save_info_to_db`.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, depending on what you prefer, but one idea is to use a Service class. In the service, you could handle the file processing.

Your controller would then end up looking something like:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
require 'csv'

def save_info_to_db
    file_service = FileProcessingService.new(file)
    file_service.save_info!
    session[:total_gross_income] = Purchase.total_gross_income(file_service.purchases_made)
    
    redirect_to display_incomes_path
rescue
    # perhaps some rescue logic in the event processing fails
end
```

All your file processing logic would go in the Service.  You could even split that logic up --  logic for getting the data from the file, then separate logic for saving the data.

Lots of options, but the general idea is you can use a service to handle logic that may span multiple models.